# How to create event listeners using a for loop in JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop, navigation

I am trying to create event listeners for a pure JS dropdown menu. When I try to create the listeners using a for loop I get an error and it doesn't work, but when I create them manually using arrays they work perfectly. What am I missing?

```
var dropDown  = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-sub__mobile-dropdown');
var subNavList  = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-sub__list');


for ( i = 0; i < dropDown.length; i++) {

    dropDown[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        subNavList[i].classList.toggle('nav-sub__list--active');
    });
}
```

The above doesn't work, but if I create the event listeners manually using the arrays it does work.

```
dropDown[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    subNavList[0].classList.toggle('nav-sub__list--active');
});

dropDown[1].addEventListener('click', function() {
    subNavList[1].classList.toggle('nav-sub__list--active');
});

dropDown[2].addEventListener('click', function() {
    subNavList[2].classList.toggle('nav-sub__list--active');
});
```

When I use the for loop I get the following error code in my console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
```

**UPDATE SOLVED PROBLEM**

I was able to solve the problem using let thanks to Ben McCormick's comment here:
[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

The solution was to simply use let in the for loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i < dropDown.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Put your eventlistener code in function(i) {} block
for ( i = 0; i < dropDown.length; i++) {
function (i) {
    dropDown[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        subNavList[i].classList.toggle('nav-sub__list--active');
    });
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Because when the click function is called, the variable `i` has the last value it held, `dropDown.length`, not the loop value at the time `addEventListener` was called.

What you want is something like this:

```
for ( i = 0; i < dropDown.length; i++) {
    function addListener(n) {
        dropDown[n].addEventListener('click', function() {
            subNavList[n].classList.toggle('nav-sub__list--active');
        });
    }
    addListener(i);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the problem when I console.log it. Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Just added more detail.